# Can't connect to OpenVPN Access Server using Network Manager configuration

Tags: server, openvpn

I usually use the terminal and type

```
sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn
```

in order to connect to my VPS on which I installed OpenVPN Access Server in order to make my own VPN. However, it's not very practical, especially when I have to switch with another VPN (Cisco, in the network manager).

So I looked it up and found that I could add an OpenVPN config to my network manager after installing `network-manager-openvpn`.

However, my config file is not recognized when I click "Import a saved VPN configuration...", it says

```
 Error: Key file contains line 'setenv FORWARD_COMPATIBLE 1' which is not a key-value pair, group, or comment.
```

I tried deleting that line, but then it's another line that's faulty, and then another, and so on.

So I tried splitting my `.ovpn` file into `ca.crt`, `client.cr`, `client.key`, using the `sacli` script that OpenVPN Access Server provides on the server itself. I put the the gateway, with and without `port/tcp/udp`, chose "Password with Certificates (TLS)", the username linked to the config file, the password, linked the different `.crt` and `.key files`, tried many different combinations of advanced parameters (use custom gateway port 443/1194, use TCP connection ON/OFF, use LZO data compression ON/OFF)... No result, after I chose the VPN connection the network manager icon shows that it tries to connect for second, shows a padlock for a split second, and goes on like this for a minute before telling me it failed.

If I try using the static key I have to fill in "Remote IP Address" and "Local IP Address", and I haven't found what they're supposed to be as I already have the gateway. I can't save the settings without them, so I tried putting the gateway in the "Remote IP Address" and "127.0.0.1" as the "Local IP Address", but when I do this it just instantly tells me "VPN Connection Failed".

Has anyone an idea of how I could finally manage to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a way to have more detail about the errors. I looked through the syslog on the client while trying to connect, and the log `openvpnas.log` at `/var/log` on the server.

I'm using the `Password with Certificates (TLS)` authentification, and apparently, in order to make the configuration right I had to go in `Advanced` then `TLS Authentification`, tick `Use additional TLS authentification`, chose the `ta.key` file and chose direction `1`. On the `General` tab I have just `Use custom gateway port` set to `443`, `Use LZO data compression` and `Use a TCP connection` ticked. I hope this can help somebody in the future, I've lost so much time on this..

Answer (score 0):

I have also had problems importing .ovpn configuration files into network manager as well.  Oddly, it works for me on some machines, but not all.

I use the "Certificates (TLS)" option so I do not know about the userid / password options.

When I have to input the individual key files I use the following options.

On a 14.04 machine I use tick Use LZO data compression (nothing else ticked on any of the advanced options screens). (This has to match the server setting).

On the General tab I tick "All users may connect to this network".

On a 16.04 machine I additionally tick Set Virtual Device Type select TUN and set name TUN